# Why isn't ConsoleAppender configured in app.config causing logs to write to the console?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

In App.Config I declare a config section for my console application:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
```

And configure a `ConsoleAppender`:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

We also declare a `RollingFile` appender in a logging util class that's part of our standard codebase at app-startup (which is not easily modified):

```
        _hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        _rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();            
        ... //_rollingFileppender options

        _rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();
        _hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(_rollingFileAppender);
        _hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

When I run the application, I see log-entries *are* written to files as expected but nothing is written to the console.

When I inspect my `ILog` instance in the debugger, I see no appenders at all in `Logger.Appenders` but I do see the `RollingFileAppender` instance as the only element in `Root.Appenders`.

log4net is something I am used to "it just works" - is there some incompatibility having config *and* code add appenders, or some line I need to get `LogManager` to *look* in app.config?

Comment: I was looking at https://blog.elmah.io/log4net-tutorial-the-complete-guide-for-beginners-and-pros/ and don't see anything really obvious I'm missing

Comment: If you comment the code that adds the rolling appender does the console one works?

Answer (score 2):

You just got me curious and i decided to play around a bit.
First observations is: **You are right**.

After some google i found this [this](http://spencerooni.github.io/2016/05/06/simple-log4net-setup.html)

### App.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %logger{1} %username - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

### Setup

```js
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;

namespace LoggerDemo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupFileAppender();
            SetupTraceAppender();
            Logger.Error("Error");
        }

        private static void SetupTraceAppender()
        {
            var patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            var trace = new TraceAppender();
            trace.Layout = patternLayout;
            trace.ActivateOptions();
            var l = (Logger)Logger.Logger;
            l.AddAppender(trace);
        }

        private static void SetupFileAppender()
        {
            var patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            var roller = new RollingFileAppender();
            roller.AppendToFile = true;
            roller.File = "Log.txt";
            roller.Layout = patternLayout;
            roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
            roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
            roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
            roller.ActivateOptions();
            var l = (Logger)Logger.Logger;
            l.AddAppender(roller);
        }
    }
}
```

### Most Important

In your AssemblyInfo add `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

### Result

[image: Result]

Comment: So this only worked for you once you added the line to AssemblyInfo? If you test adding the code I have do both appenders work? I can't tell if my problem is config driven, or if the programatic appender is messing things up

Comment: Correct. Seems to be an issue with the appender. If you want a console-output, you have to modify the Assemblyinfo to get things work. For any other appenders we had never issues (File, Registry, SQL, 3rd Party)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these help - the scripted appender never works alongside the coded one. I can't tell if you've tested this alongside the programatic version do you have a MCE?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Modified the main-code. The other parts stay the same. .net Framework 4.7.2 was used with latest Nuget-version of Log4Net. Works like a charm here :/

Answer (score 0):

I looked in google about log4net and seems interesting. I looked into some website and
for the output here should be something like log4net.config i guess? The guy showed to press it and in the Properties here should be "Copy to Output Directory": "Copy Always".
Maybe you can somehow figure to use it and print into the console the output. Here is really useful information in google about it you can click [Here](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) to read more.
Hope i somehow helped you :)